# C Macro: How to validate arguments passed to a widechar mask in a macro?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I currently have a macro that receives a mask and the arguments for filling that mask.

I'm trying to create a validation of the arguments passed to a macro during compilation, as is done in the **printf** function, to ensure that the parameters are correct and do not cause any errors during program execution.

I created a code that performs this validation, but only for strings of **char** type.

An example of the test:

```
void ValidateMask(const char *FormatString, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

void
ValidateMask (
  const char *FormatString,
  ...
  )
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, FormatString);
  vprintf(FormatString, args);
  va_end(args);
}

#define DEBUG_LOG(string_format, ...) \
  ValidateMask(string_format)

int main()
{
    ValidateMask("This is a test: %d %s\n", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

However, due to the environment where I'm performing the tests, the strings are of type **char16**.

I'm trying to remove the '**L**' character before the strings during the compilation process using macros but I haven't been successful yet.

Example: `DEBUG_LOG(L"This is a test: %d\n", 42)`

I would like to know if there is any way to perform this validation using this technique for widechar or if there is another way to perform this validation during compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [bug 38308](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38308), [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) has never, and probably never will, support `-Wformat` warnings or `__attribute__((format(wprintf, 1, 2)));` for `wchar_t`s, so you can not use this to validate your arguments.

Otherwise, you would be able to catch both using a `_Generic` macro. Example:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

// const char* version:
void ValidateMaskc(const char* FormatString, ...)
    __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

void ValidateMaskc(const char* FormatString, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, FormatString);
    vprintf(FormatString, args);
    va_end(args);
}

// const wchar_t* version:
void ValidateMaskw(const wchar_t* FormatString, ...)
    __attribute__((format(wprintf, 1, 2)));

void ValidateMaskw(const wchar_t* FormatString, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, FormatString);
    vwprintf(FormatString, args);
    va_end(args);
}

#define ValidateMask(F, ...)        \
    _Generic((F),                   \
        char*: ValidateMaskc,       \
        const char*: ValidateMaskc, \
        wchar_t*: ValidateMaskw,    \
        const wchar_t*: ValidateMaskw)(F __VA_OPT__(, ) __VA_ARGS__)

#define DEBUG_LOG(string_format, ...) ValidateMask(string_format)

int main(void) {
    // this would have triggered:
    ValidateMask(L"This is a test: %d %s\n", 42);

    // but now, only this will
    ValidateMask("This is a test: %d %s\n", 42); 
}
```